# Activeadmin batch action caching query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, activeadmin, active-record-query

I am using a batch action in activeadmin to display a form and code is

```
batch_action 'Assign something', form: {
      abc: Abc.order('name ASC').map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.uniq
  } do |ids, inputs|
    ids.each do |id|
      job = Job.find(id)
      # does something here
    end
    redirect_to :back, notice: "Congrats!!"
  end
```

This code generates perfect form but in this form dropdown generated has cached values. That is if we modify **name** of any **Abc** record, its change is not reflected in the form even after refreshing the page.

```
Form has following options

<option value="6">Bla</option>
<option value="7">Alliance</option>
```

After editing value Bla to Foo in DB our form still shows same old result. Though value in db has been changed.

```
After editing records. Though Bla should be changed to Foo now
<option value="6">Bla</option>
<option value="7">Alliance</option>
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [doc](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/1c85c5654a2ce1d43d4c64d98b928ff133d46406/docs/9-batch-actions.md#batch-action-forms), dynamic forms need a proc.

```
batch_action ('Assign something', form: ->{ {
  abc: Abc.order('name ASC').map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.uniq
} }) do |ids, inputs|
ids.each do |id|
  job = Job.find(id)
  # does something here
end
redirect_to :back, notice: "Congrats!!"
```

end

I think the block passed as an argument and the block after the function call are less confusing (slightly) with the `()` around the arguments.  They are not required.